# Hotkey to scroll through method overload options in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide, hotkeys

Is there a keyboard hot-key to scroll through multiple IntelliSense method overload options for Visual C# pro?

I.e. do what the arrows do if you click on them in the pic below.

[image: IntelliPic]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you type the "(" the up and down arrows will navigate through the overloads for you when the tooltip is visible.

Comment: Haha, so easy. I tried all kinds of shift and ctr keys, but never just the arrow keys. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How do you do this in VS 2010?

Found it: You can use Shift+Tab to "move back" and after that Up and Down works.

Cheers,
Robert